# how to get file names using find in shell script

Tags: shell

I have log files named `SMS_18_06_2014_15_03_43.log, SMS_18_06_2014_15_03_00.log, SMS_18_06_2014_15_03_21.log`.

When I am using `find *18_06_2014_15_03*.log*` I am able to find all file names with this time stamp. But when using shell script it is giving me 0.

here is my script

```
LOGGER_PATH=/FULL_LOGGER_PATH

file_stamp_1=$(date --date="75min ago" +"%d_%m_%Y_%H_%M")
file_stamp_2=$(date --date="74min ago" +"%d_%m_%Y_%H_%M")
file_stamp_3=$(date --date="73min ago" +"%d_%m_%Y_%H_%M")
file_stamp_4=$(date --date="72min ago" +"%d_%m_%Y_%H_%M")
file_stamp_5=$(date --date="71min ago" +"%d_%m_%Y_%H_%M")
file_stamp_6=$(date --date="70min ago" +"%d_%m_%Y_%H_%M")
file_stamp_7=$(date --date="69min ago" +"%d_%m_%Y_%H_%M")
file_stamp_8=$(date --date="68min ago" +"%d_%m_%Y_%H_%M")
file_stamp_9=$(date --date="67min ago" +"%d_%m_%Y_%H_%M")
file_stamp_10=$(date --date="66min ago" +"%d_%m_%Y_%H_%M")
file_stamp_11=$(date --date="65min ago" +"%d_%m_%Y_%H_%M")
file_stamp_12=$(date --date="64min ago" +"%d_%m_%Y_%H_%M")
file_stamp_13=$(date --date="63min ago" +"%d_%m_%Y_%H_%M")
file_stamp_14=$(date --date="62min ago" +"%d_%m_%Y_%H_%M")
file_stamp_15=$(date --date="61min ago" +"%d_%m_%Y_%H_%M")

for i in {1..15}
do
    set file_stamp_$i
    echo ${!1}
    Mins_log_files=`find -name $LOGGER_PATH/*${!1}*.log* -atime -75 | sort | uniq -d`;
    Log_file_count=`echo "$Mins_log_files" | wc -w`
    echo "Log_file_count = $Log_file_count"
done
```

Please guide me how can I get specific file names with time stamp.

Comment: Why don't you `find -name $LOGGER_PATH/file_stamp_${i}*.log}` directly? Indirect expansion `${!var}` does not work in shell, just in bash.

Comment: @fedorqui... It is also not working. I tried this also.

Comment: if you were not lucky, you may have two `file_stamp_xx` vars with same value.  think about `file_..._1` was on `y-m-d 01:01:59.999` after `1ms` the date would be changed into `... 01:02:00`... you get what I meant.

Comment: @Kent... Yes I got it. But I am considering it only upto minute. So I think seconds will not be a big problem, if all goes fine.

Comment: Finally I figured it out. Please check my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I got this answer so here is updated and working script.
I remove `-atime -75 | sort | uniq -d` this portion of command.

```
LOGGER_PATH=/FULL_LOGGER_PATH

file_stamp_1=$(date --date="75min ago" +"%d_%m_%Y_%H_%M")
file_stamp_2=$(date --date="74min ago" +"%d_%m_%Y_%H_%M")
file_stamp_3=$(date --date="73min ago" +"%d_%m_%Y_%H_%M")
file_stamp_4=$(date --date="72min ago" +"%d_%m_%Y_%H_%M")
file_stamp_5=$(date --date="71min ago" +"%d_%m_%Y_%H_%M")
file_stamp_6=$(date --date="70min ago" +"%d_%m_%Y_%H_%M")
file_stamp_7=$(date --date="69min ago" +"%d_%m_%Y_%H_%M")
file_stamp_8=$(date --date="68min ago" +"%d_%m_%Y_%H_%M")
file_stamp_9=$(date --date="67min ago" +"%d_%m_%Y_%H_%M")
file_stamp_10=$(date --date="66min ago" +"%d_%m_%Y_%H_%M")
file_stamp_11=$(date --date="65min ago" +"%d_%m_%Y_%H_%M")
file_stamp_12=$(date --date="64min ago" +"%d_%m_%Y_%H_%M")
file_stamp_13=$(date --date="63min ago" +"%d_%m_%Y_%H_%M")
file_stamp_14=$(date --date="62min ago" +"%d_%m_%Y_%H_%M")
file_stamp_15=$(date --date="61min ago" +"%d_%m_%Y_%H_%M")

for i in {1..15}
do
    set file_stamp_$i
    echo ${!1}
    Mins_log_files=`find $LOGGER_PATH/${!1}*.log*`;
    Log_file_count=`echo "$Mins_log_files" | wc -w`
    echo "Log_file_count = $Log_file_count"
done
```

But here next question is why find is not checking file names with `sort` and `uniq` commands. Can anybody explain me this?